# How does ValueListenableProvider differ from ChangeNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, provider

How does ValueListenableProvider differ from ChangeNotifierProvider? Here is one of the definitions of ValueListenableProvider:

> This provider is used to provide a ValueListenable object to its
> descendants. ValueListenable is similar to ChangeNotifier, but it only
> notifies its listeners when the value changes.

But ChangeNotifier also notifies its listeners when its property changes, doesn't it?

Or is the implication that ValueListenable will automatically notify listeners without having to call notifyListeners?

Answer (score 1):

`ValueListenableProvider` and `ChangeNotifierProvider` are both providers in the Flutter framework used for managing state. They have some differences in terms of the type of state they manage and how they notify consumers about state changes.

**Type of State:**

`ValueListenableProvider` manages state that implements the `ValueListenable` interface. `ValueListenable` is a class in Flutter that provides a way to listen for changes to a value.

`ChangeNotifierProvider` manages state that extends the `ChangeNotifier` class. `ChangeNotifier` is a class in Flutter that provides a way to notify listeners when the object has changed.

**Usage:**

`ValueListenableProvider` is useful when you have a value that can be listened to for changes, such as a `ValueNotifier` or any other custom class that implements `ValueListenable`.

`ChangeNotifierProvider` is useful when you have a class that extends `ChangeNotifier` and you want to notify listeners when the state of that object changes.

Read - [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html), [ValueListenableProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ValueListenableProvider-class.html)

`ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => new MyChangeNotifier(),
  child: Container()
)
```

`ValueListenableProvider`:

```
ValueListenable<int> foo;

ValueListenableProvider<int>.value(
  valueListenable: foo,
  child: Container(),
);
```